# Prove that if $A,B \subseteq [0,\infty)$, then $\sup(AB) = \sup(A)\sup(B)$

Tags: calculus

> Prove that if $A,B \subseteq [0,\infty)$, then $\sup(AB) = \sup(A)\sup(B)$ and $\inf(AB) = \inf(A)\inf(B)$.

We show the property for the supremum first. we see that since for any $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ we have $\sup{A}\sup{B} \geq ab$, we have $\sup{A}\sup{B} \geq \sup{AB}$. For  the other direction, we know there exist $a,b$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ such that $a \geq \sup{A}-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $b \geq \sup{B}-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. We can't just simply multiply these since the RHS may be negative, so I don't know what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: if $\sup A =0 $ or $\sup B =0 $, then this equality obviously hold.

Case 2: if $\sup A \not=0 $ and $\sup B \not=0 $, then you can pick $\epsilon$ such that $\frac \epsilon 2 < \sup A$ and $\frac \epsilon 2 < \sup B$.

Comment: I don't understand your case 2 and what it shows.

Comment: Note that (for example) $\sup A \not=0 $ which will imply that $\sup A > 0 $. The other is similar.

Comment: How does that mean $\sup(AB) = \sup{A}\sup{B}$?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, assume $0<c<\sup A\sup B$. Then $0<\frac c{\sup B}<\sup A$ so that tehre exists $a\in A$ with $a>\frac c{\sup B}$. Then $\sup B >\frac ca$, hence there exists $b\in B$ with $b>\frac ca$. Then $ab>c$, hence $\sup AB >c$

Answer (score 0):

I preassume that here $\sup\varnothing=0$. This because we are working in set $[0,\infty)$.

Suppose that $\sup A\cdot\sup B>\sup AB$.

Then $\sup A$ and $\sup B$ are both positive, so $A$ and $B$ are both non-empty.

Let $a_n\to\sup A$ with $a_n\in A$ and let $b_n\to\sup B$ with $b_n\in B$

Then $a_nb_n\to \sup A\cdot\sup B$ so that $a_nb_n>\sup AB$ for $n$ large enough.

Contradiction is found.